# Past Perfect vs. Simple Past Usage

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past

I've been brushing up on the past perfect tense recently, and after reading the following sentence on a website, I feel like it's missing a key element:

> "Many progressives, who thought well of Wilson's dream of a new world order, drew back in revulsion 
>   when the terms of the treaty were published."

Shouldn't there be a *had* after *who*?

Comment: You should check out the [back-shift](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backshifting) 'tag' on the site.

Answer (score 2):

The [Past Perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html) expresses the idea that something occurred before another action in the past. It can also show that something happened before a specific time in the past.

> Emma had never seen an R-rated movie *until* she was 16.

In the above, the past perfect refers to something that happened before something else in the past.

> Many progressives, who thought well of Wilson's dream of a new world order, drew back in revulsion when the terms of the treaty were published.

Your example doesn't describe such a scenario. It doesn't say that the progressives changed their way of thinking; it only says that they drew back in revulsion at the terms of the treaty. The *who thought well of Wilson's dream of a new world order*, describes the progressives. It seems to me to be akin to:

> The progressives, who were liberally inclined, were horrified by the terms of the treaty.

Comment: "Many progressives drew back in revulsion when the terms of the treaty were published. Before its publishing, they had thought well of Wilson's dream of a new world order." Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure, because I don't have the context. *Before* and *after* specifically obviate the need for past perfect. However, I think my analysis stands on it's own. Maybe someone else will have a better answer. :)

Comment: You need to bear in mind that "Wilson's dream of a new world order" is not the same thing as "the treaty".  People may like the former and dislike the latter, so this sentence is not saying anything about a **change** to how they thought about Wilson's dream.  It says they liked his dream and didn't like the treaty (which is perhaps what his dream turned into, after various compromises etc).

Comment: It's like saying "Some people, who liked apples, didn't like the apple pie".